# set custom message in each different error validation in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

let say that I have set in model for validation like this

```
validates :tel, presence: true , length: { minimum: 10,  maximum: 11 }, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

how do I can display a custom message in view for each validate.

when I set this in views page.

```
<% if @diary.errors.include?(:tel) %>    
      <div class="err"><p><%= @diary.errors.full_messages_for(:tel).join("") %></p></div>
<% end %>
```

it directly displays all error message. I want to make a display in view like this

```
if(error_require)
   echo "tel is needed"
else if(error_length)
   echo "tel is to long"
else 
   echo "tel must numeric"
end
```

can I make like that?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `message` in separate hashes for each validator:

```
validates :tel,
          presence: { message: 'is needed' },
          length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 11, too_long: 'is too long' },
          numericality: { only_integer: true, message: 'must be numeric' }
```

Read more about [presence](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence), [length](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length), and [numericality](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) validators.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to define methods for each type of validation (in your model) like this:

```
validate :chech_length

def chech_length
  if tel.length < 10 || tel.length > 11

      errors.add(:base, "tel is too long!") 
   end
end



validate :check_if_present

def check_if_present

  if tel.blank?
     errors.add(:base, "tel must be present!")
  end
end
```

etc...

Hope this helps.